# Android WebView shows "Resource not found"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview, android-websettings

I Want to open a WeView inside my App. It works fine for few pages navigation, then suddenly it shows "Resource not found". Here is my code. Am I missing something here.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://xyz.example.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will not answer your question, but you can remove this line `view.loadUrl(url);` and return false instead

Answer (score 1):

Return false instead of true in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://xyz.example.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```